# Create unordered list from JSON object using JS (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I would like to create an unordered list using jQuery `.each()` for the JSON `entry` object in the code below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20title%2C%20description%2C%20link%2C%20pubDate%0AFROM%20feed(0%2C5)%0AWHERE%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.feedburner.com%2FffAggregator'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=friendFeed",
        data: { get_param: 'value' },
        success: function (data) {
            var names = data

            $('#results').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

I would like to achieve this with JavaScript (jQuery) alone

Comment: Too easy a question for you not to show any attempt.

Comment: I've updated the code to the furthest that I got. Sorry for not including it earlier. This displays the JSON string on the screen for which I would like to make into an unordered list

Comment: i dont know the yahoo api but i looks like you are reciving a JSON object nested in a function call. do you have a function called friendFeed? and do that not return the data as JSON?

Comment: @VeXii That's called JSONP, it's working fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set JSONP as data type in your AJAX request and specifiy `friendFeed` as callback function.

In the success callback function, you can then build the unordered list directly from the JSON data. Just iterate over the object you want to use and append `li` elements to a `ul` element. Example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20title%2C%20description%2C%20link%2C%20pubDate%0AFROM%20feed(0%2C5)%0AWHERE%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.feedburner.com%2FffAggregator'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=friendFeed",
    data: { get_param: 'value' },
    jsonpCallback: 'friendFeed',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        var obj = data.query.results.entry,  // get entry object (array) from JSON data
            ul = $("<ul>");                    // create a new ul element
        // iterate over the array and build the list
        for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; ++i) {
            ul.append("<li><a href='" + obj[i].link.href + "'>" + obj[i].title.content + "</a></li>");
        }
        $("#results").append(ul);    // add the list to the DOM
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't have to specify a callback, jQuery sets it automatically if you remove it from the url http://jsfiddle.net/wAvRk/1/

Comment: @Juan Mendes: Thanks for the hint! I added the callback here because I didn't want to change the URL given in the question (might have been confusing).